# How to change specific terminal color settings on Mac

Tags: macos, vim, colors, terminal

I have recently installed clang_complete plugin for VIM. Everything looks fine except in popup menu I get a Pink background color which is uncomfortable.

[image: VIM clang_complete image]

How do I change this color?
Also is there a way to change some other colors, like manual description, directory colors(in vim) etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These colors are defined in your colorscheme.

You can [search for a better colorscheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color%20scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) or edit the one you are using now. Here is an example:

```
hi Pmenu      term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermbg=238 ctermfg=231 gui=NONE guibg=#444444 guifg=#ffffff
hi PmenuSel   term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermbg=149 ctermfg=16  gui=NONE guibg=#b1d631 guifg=#000000
hi PmenuSbar  term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermbg=250 ctermfg=fg  gui=NONE guibg=#bebebe guifg=fg
hi PmenuThumb term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermbg=149 ctermfg=149 gui=NONE guibg=#b1d631 guifg=#b1d631
```

If you use a default colorscheme, you can add the lines above to your ~/.vimrc.

Comment: You should learn to accept and vote on answers that has been helpful to you.